# System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode when running within transactionScope

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm trying to call a DB sp I wrote

from within c# transactionScope

```
public static void RunInTransaction(Action logic)
{
    var options = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted };
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options))
    {
        logic();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

where `logic` is actually calling the `sp` from `c#`.

And I get the following error:

> System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode

Comment: do you have a distributed transaction here, and it's a message from DTS?

Comment: This can happen if running code from remote computer and DTS is disabled

Comment: @EladBenda I found the solution from `@ruspava` very interesting (and most likely helpful to others, as well). Was your issue related to a typo in `RegexPattern`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems weird but might be related: If you have the following piece of code:

```
private static readonly RegexPattern = "...";
```

and *that pattern is invalid* (mine was missing a parenthesis), then you generate `COMPlusExceptionCode`-exceptions when the containing class if initially loaded. (I managed this and I'm not even touching a database)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Servis kapalı. bilgisayar hizmetler bölümünde Sql service > start etmelisiniz

google translate:Sql service is off. Sql service> in the computer services section should start